# ffmpeg and QSV works on three PCs, but not the fourth

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding

As the title suggests, I've used ffmpeg with x264_qsv hardware acceleration on two Windows 7 systems and one Windows 10 system successfully.  I have now tried to set it up on a fourth system which is Windows 7, and it doesn't work.  I'm getting an error which is new to me.  This system has an i3-2120 processor, which the Intel web site says supports QSV encoding.  I have downloaded what Intel says is the most recent driver and installed it (and rebooted) and there are no visible problems.  I have cut the processing commands down to the minimum for the test:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -err_detect ignore_err -loglevel verbose ^
 -stats -benchmark ^
 -init_hw_device qsv:hw,child_device_type=qsv  ^
 -hwaccel_output_format qsv -vsync vfr -ec deblock ^
 -ss "00:24:30.544" -to "00:25:33.393" ^
 -i "InputFile.avi" ^
 -strict normal -c:a aac -q:a 1.5 ^
 -c:v h264_qsv -q:v 28 -preset veryslow ^
 -movflags +faststart ^
 "OutputFile.mp4" > test1.log 2>&1
```

This is the captured log file:

```
Routing option err_detect to both codec and muxer layer
Routing option strict to both codec and muxer layer
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0000000000564ac0] Using D3D9Ex device.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 00000000005649c0] Initialize MFX session: API version is 1.34, implementation version is 1.4
[avi @ 0000000005631bc0] non-interleaved AVI
[h264 @ 0000000000581540] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: yuv422p
Input #0, avi, from 'InputFile.avi':
  Duration: 02:16:34.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4495 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:2:2), 1 reference frame (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv422p(progressive, left), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4281 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 120 tbc
  Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 00000000066a1540] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: yuv422p
[graph_1_in_0_1 @ 0000000006c52540] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0000000006c52a40] w:1280 h:720 pixfmt:yuv422p tb:83333/5000000 fr:60/1 sar:1/1
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0000000006c52e40] w:iw h:ih flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[format @ 0000000006c52d40] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scaler_0' between the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'format'
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0000000006c52e40] w:1280 h:720 fmt:yuv422p sar:1/1 -> w:1280 h:720 fmt:nv12 sar:1/1 flags:0x4
[h264_qsv @ 00000000067f32c0] Using device qsv0 (type qsv) with h264_qsv encoder.
[h264_qsv @ 00000000067f32c0] Encoder: input is system memory surface
[h264_qsv @ 00000000067f32c0] Using the constant quantization parameter (CQP) ratecontrol method
[h264_qsv @ 00000000067f32c0] Error querying encoder params: unsupported (-3)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
bench: maxrss=113992kB
[AVIOContext @ 00000000066a1040] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
[aac @ 00000000063f42c0] Qavg: nan
[aac @ 00000000063f42c0] 1 frames left in the queue on closing
[AVIOContext @ 0000000005631700] Statistics: 12998952 bytes read, 196 seeks
Conversion failed!
```

It appears to me that the QSV hardware is being found and activated, but I don't understand why there is an error "Error querying encoder params: unsupported (-3)".  I have seen a similar error when trying to encode a 2160p video, which is beyond the range of the encoder: but this video is 1280x720 at 60 fps and about 4000 kbps, which should be well within the range of the x264_qsv encoder.
Furthermore, I have encoded files like this from the same source on the two Windows 7 and one Windows 10 system I have with no problems.  I am using ffmpeg.exe which I copied from one of the working systems, so I know the executable works.  I've done web searches on the error, and have not found a relevant post.  I looked through the index here for "QSV" and I don't think this error has been reported before.

Can anyone please suggest a cause, and hopefully a fix, for this problem? Getting this close to a working system and having this error is causing a great deal of stress.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try minimising your ffmpeg command down to just the essentials? Something like `fmpeg -init_hw_device qsv:hw,child_device_type=qsv  -hwaccel_output_format qsv -i "InputFile.avi" -c:a aac -c:v h264_qsv "OutputFile.mp4"` just to make sure that the hardware works without all the cruft.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: however, I tried the totally stripped down command, and the result is unchanged.  I get exactly the same error.

Comment: Seems odd and I can find only one single link with the same `Error querying encoder params: unsupported (-3)` and it was unresolved as not repeatable. Can you update the graphics drivers? Maybe you have a slightly old version that is missing some feature...

Comment: I have what Intel says is the most recent driver, it downloads as win64_152824.exe, In Device manager, it shows up as Version 9.17.10.5229, Date 5/26/2015, and "Update" says it's the proper driver.  I do have some Dell hardware updates I plan to try installing after the current test encoding (without QSV) finishes, which should be in a few hours.  But if anyone knows of a driver that is newer than the one I have, I'd like to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total newbie when it comes to ffmpeg, but I'm feeling that this might be caused by an unsupported pixel format (by that processor).

Your capture:

> [h264 @ 0000000000581540] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: yuv422p

Can you try changing the pixel format to `yuv420p`, `nv12` or `yuyv422` and try again?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I believe I mentioned that three other systems will process these exact same files successfully using the ffmpeg commands I have shown here. However, I did also try with -pix_format yuv420p and it made no difference.  I have searched for everything I can find on the Intel web site and on the Dell web site and I can't find anything else that will install that will change the graphics driver or add additional control software.

Comment: Just to be certain I didn't accidentally entered something incorrectly, I copied my inputfile and the BAT file with the ffmpeg command I have posted here to one of my other systems.  The batch file ran correctly. This shows that the error is somewhere in the hardware or software of the fourth system, as the video file and batch procedure work when copied to a different system.  Also, it's not necessary to include -pix_format, the software selects a compatible format supported by h264_qsv for the output.

Comment: I have been told the issue is closed because it as resolved: but anyone who reads this can see that there is no resolution or solution.